# How to use bucket selector aggregation with date range aggregation?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

Whenever I try to use bucket selector aggregate for date range aggregate I get this error.

```
buckets_path must reference either a number value or a single value numeric metric aggregation, got: [Object[]] at aggregation [agg1]
```

This is the query that is trying to get all the users (parent document) who have bought a particular product in the last 180 days with the total amount greater than, say 200. I want to filter out the parent documents which satisfy this aggregation.
User(parent) > transactions(child)

```
  "aggs": {
    "group_by_id": {
      "composite": {
        "sources": [
          {
            "id": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "user_id"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "aggs": {
        "total_transactions": {
          "children": {
            "type": "transaction_list"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "range_bucket": {
              "date_range": {
                "field": "transaction_list.transaction_date",
                "ranges": [{
                  "from": "now-180d/d",
                  "to": "now",
                  "key": "bucket"
                }]
              },
              "aggs": {
                "item_filter": {
                  "filter": {
                    "term": {
                      "transaction_list.inventories.item_id": "1234"
                    }
                  },
                  "aggs": {
                    "item_total": {
                      "sum": {
                        "field": "transaction_list.inventory_total"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "inventory_selector": {
          "bucket_selector": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "total": "total_transactions > range_bucket > item_filter > item_total"
            },
            "script": "params.total > 200"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```